# ctypes, problem with output format function c++

Tags: python, c++, return, ctypes

I created a ctype function that calls a C ++ library that connects to a socket and sends it a 5 bytes hex packet. The function connects send the hex code I write I input the peripheral responds (I checked with Wireshark) in a correct way but the python code with ctype fails to interopet well the packet it receives as a response (always 5 bytes). Can anyone give me any suggestions? Where am I wrong? Attached I enclose the C ++ code with the code or python and the answer of the function.

I have already tried c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER (LP_c_char), ctypes.POINTER (LP_c_char), but nothing the return of the function is always 0

C++ Code connect_pe_func.cpp

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sstream>

extern "C" char * connect_pe_func(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sockfd, n;
   int connected = 0;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
   std::string serveraddr = argv[0];

   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serveraddr.c_str());
   servaddr.sin_port = htons(9761);

   connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   std::string pref_hex;
   std::string hex("0x");
   std::string test = argv[1];
   size_t numbytes = test.size() / 2;
   uint8_t command[numbytes];

   for (size_t w = 0, x = 0; w < numbytes; ++w, x += 2)
   {
      pref_hex = hex + test.substr(x, 2);
      //cout << pref_hex;
      command[w] = stoi(pref_hex, nullptr, 16);
   }

   int bytes_to_send = sizeof(command);

   send(sockfd, command, bytes_to_send, 0);
   uint8_t output_command[numbytes];
   recv(sockfd, output_command, bytes_to_send, 0);
   close(sockfd);
   char test_out[10];

   for (size_t w = 0, x = 0; w < numbytes; ++w, x += 2)
   {
      test_out[x] = (char)output_command[w];
   }
   return test_out;

}
```

python code

```py
import sys
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./connect_pe_func.so')

LP_c_char = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)
LP_LP_c_char = ctypes.POINTER(LP_c_char)

lib.connect_pe_func.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, LP_LP_c_char)
lib.connect_pe_func.restypes = ctypes.c_char_p
argv = ["192.168.2.170","2600000026"]
argc = len(argv)

p = (LP_c_char*len(argv))()
for i, arg in enumerate(argv):  # not sys.argv, but argv!!!
  enc_arg = arg.encode('utf-8')
  p[i] = ctypes.create_string_buffer(enc_arg)

na = ctypes.cast(p, LP_LP_c_char)

lib.connect_pe_func(argc, na)
```

I expected the output of python code like 26810000a7, but the actual output is always 0

Comment: For starters, `char test_out[10];` contents is not guaranteed to exist after exiting the function, so there is ***Undefined Behavior***. You should *malloc* it (then you'd need a separate func to *free* it). But in these cases it's best to have another argument to the function, instead of the return value. Caller will allocate the buffer, func will populate its contents, then caller will do whatever with the buffer.

Comment: can you give me an example?